# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.notifyAfter instead of HTTP 404 page not found

Tags: jsf-2, http-status-code-404, facelets

We are using JSF2.0.2 in weblogic10.3 , we are handling FileNotFound or Page Not Found in web.xml with 404 error page.

```
          webapp->             
                  folder-a->page1.xhtml
                            page2.xhtml
```

If we request a page which is not a inside folder-a , for example page3.xhtml ,then it is not caught by web.xml 404 ,instead it falls in to JSF layer and results in below exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.notifyAfter(RestoreViewPhase.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the early Mojarra version which will occur when you've a `PhaseListener` configured which should execute while restoring the view, but the `UIViewRoot` is `null`. This bug was introduced in Mojarra 2.0.4 and has been reported as [issue 1764](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1764) and is been fixed since Mojarra version 2.1.0 as per the report (and 2.0.6 as per the source code). So, upgrading to at least that version should fix that problem.

After you've upgraded Mojarra, you'll hit another problem. Mojarra doesn't send a 404 when the view is not found, but instead throws a `com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException` which is a subclass of `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. So this ends up as a HTTP 500 response. So if you configured the error page on error code of 404, then it won't be shown at all, but instead the error page on error code of 500 or the closest match on the exception type will be shown instead. You'd need to configure the error page as follows instead:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

or if you don't want to be JSF implementation dependent

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.FileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: balucs...thanks for the reply....adding both FacesFileNotFoundException or FileNotFoundException in web.xml didn't solve the problem.. I will disable the phaselistener and see

Comment: Perhaps you missed the statement in the 1st paragraph that your problem is caused by a bug in Mojarra? Of course alone adding the new exception types won't fix it. This is only the fix **after** you have upgraded Mojarra. You need to upgrade to at least Mojarra 2.0.4.

Comment: Sorry, I confused the versions. The bug was introduced in 2.0.4 and fixed in 2.1.0 (and 2.0.6). You however said that you were using 2.0.2? What is this?

Comment: Oh ok...i checked now...we are using the one from weblogic10.3.4 ,which provide JSF2.0.4 .anyhow thanks for clarification